# Why is multiplication axiomatized?

Tags: real-analysis

When we learned exponentiation, we first introduced it as an iterated multiplication (for integer powers), then using nth root we defined it for rational powers, and finally we took the limit to define it for arbitrary real power.

My question: why can't we do the same with multiplication? Why is multiplication defined with axioms, rather than as an iterated addition?

Comment: Multiplication of natural numbers is, indeed, defined as an iterated addition. Now, how would you define a more general multiplication, say that of compatible matrices, as an iterated addition? I guess I'm saying that in abstract algebra (e.g. ring theory) multiplication is axiomatized largely as a space saving device. Within the context of some abstract setting defining multiplication from scratch would be costly, and also **heavily dependant** on the particular ring. Therefore, for maximum applicability of the resulting theory, it is best to leave it as an axiom.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Matrix multiplication is a different matter, in my question I was thinking of real multiplication only.

Comment: Well, in any construction of the real numbers, say as equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences, the multiplication of real numbers is defined relying on the multiplication of rational numbers. Which in turn is defined based on the multiplication of integers. Which in turn is defined based on the multiplication of natural numbers, which is defined as an iterated addition.

Comment: The properties and calculation rules of the natural numbers have been axiomatized by Peano. The axiomatization of the rational numbers was done by Dedekind. You can construct the real numbers out of the rational numbers by Dedekind cuts or Cauchy sequences.

Comment: What happens is that when we teach, for example calculus, we have powerful reasons (= pressure from physics and engineering departments) to sweep a number of things under the rug. It works, because students have been exposed to multiplication of reals in school. The axioms are introduced to have something to lean on at that point, so that a theory of calculus can be built on something. The foundations of that building are often only established in a later course, when the real numbers are constructed, and the axioms are checked and verified.

Answer (score -1):

My understanding is that standard propositional logic, which has axioms for multiplication and addition, is complicated enough to be undecidable etc. (Gödel's theorems). However, an axiom set that uses only addition is decidable and is thus much less powerful. I don't understand why using multiplication is sufficient to get the full power of mathematics while addition is not sufficient, but that is the case logically.

Perhaps I should state explicitly that I am talking about the natural numbers, not the real numbers, but I think that the point of the power of multiplication (excuse the pun) is relevant.